# Selecting option from optgroup

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select an option from optgroup using the following codes :

```
currency = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'currencySelection_dropdown')]"))
currency.select_by_visible_text("U.S. Dollar (USD)")
```

but I get the following excepetion:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <script>
```

The html source of the dropdown I'm trying to select from is :

```
<select name="ppw-0h_PU_CUS_3cf45326-7ff2-49d1-b8a6-7834ec737a68_currencySelection_dropdown" autocomplete="off" id="pmts-portal-bbb6ae6f-f79e-4a31-bc4a-7128cea6c9c9" tabindex="0" class="a-native-dropdown a-declarative" data-action="a-dropdown-select"><option class="a-prompt" value="">Select card currency</option><optgroup><option value="AUD">Australian Dollar (AUD)</option><option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option><option value="GBP">Pound Sterling (GBP)</option><option value="USD">U.S. Dollar (USD)</option></optgroup><optgroup><option value="AFN">Afghan Afghani (AFN)</option><option value="ALL">Albanian Lek (ALL)</option><option value="DZD">Algerian Dinar (DZD)</option><option value="AOA">Angolan Kwanza (AOA)</option><option value="ARS">Argentine Peso (ARS)</option><option value="AMD">Armenian Dram (AMD)</option><option value="AWG">Aruban Florin (AWG)</option><option value="AUD">Australian Dollar (AUD)</option><option value="AZN">Azerbaijani Manat (AZN)</option><option value="BSD">Bahamian Dollar (BSD)</option><option value="BHD">Bahraini Dinar (BHD)</option><option value="BDT">Bangladeshi Taka (BDT)</option><option value="BBD">Barbados Dollar (BBD)</option><option value="BYR">Belarusian Ruble (BYR)</option><option value="BZD">Belize Dollar (BZD)</option><option value="BMD">Bermudian Dollar (BMD)</option><option value="BTN">Bhutanese Ngultrum (BTN)</option><option value="BOB">Bolivian Boliviano (BOB)</option><option value="BAM">Bosnia and Herzegovina Convertible Mark (BAM)</option><option value="BWP">Botswana Pula (BWP)</option><option value="BRL">Brazilian Real (BRL)</option><option value="BND">Brunei Dollar (BND)</option><option value="BGN">Bulgarian Lev (BGN)</option><option value="BIF">Burundi Franc (BIF)</option><option value="XOF">CFA Franc BCEAO (XOF)</option><option value="XAF">CFA Franc BEAC (XAF)</option><option value="XPF">CFP Franc (XPF)</option><option value="KHR">Cambodian Riel (KHR)</option><option value="CAD">Canadian Dollar (CAD)</option><option value="CVE">Cape Verde Escudo (CVE)</option><option value="KYD">Cayman Islands Dollar (KYD)</option><option value="CLP">Chilean Peso (CLP)</option><option value="CNY">Chinese Yuan (CNY)</option><option value="COP">Colombian Peso (COP)</option><option value="KMF">Comoro Franc (KMF)</option><option value="CDF">Congolese Franc (CDF)</option><option value="CRC">Costa Rican Colon (CRC)</option><option value="HRK">Croatian Kuna (HRK)</option><option value="CZK">Czech Koruna (CZK)</option><option value="DKK">Danish Krone (DKK)</option><option value="DJF">Djibouti Franc (DJF)</option><option value="DOP">Dominican Peso (DOP)</option><option value="XCD">East Caribbean Dollar (XCD)</option><option value="EGP">Egyptian Pound (EGP)</option><option value="ERN">Eritrean Nakfa (ERN)</option><option value="ETB">Ethiopian Birr (ETB)</option><option value="EUR">Euro (EUR)</option><option value="FKP">Falkland Islands Pound (FKP)</option><option value="FJD">Fiji Dollar (FJD)</option><option value="GMD">Gambian Dalasi (GMD)</option><option value="GEL">Georgian Lari (GEL)</option><option value="GHS">Ghana Cedi (GHS)</option><option value="GIP">Gibraltar Pound (GIP)</option><option value="GTQ">Guatemalan Quetzal (GTQ)</option><option value="GNF">Guinean Franc (GNF)</option><option value="GYD">Guyanese Dollar (GYD)</option><option value="HTG">Haitian Gourde (HTG)</option><option value="HNL">Honduran Lempira (HNL)</option><option value="HKD">Hong Kong Dollar (HKD)</option><option value="HUF">Hungarian Forint (HUF)</option><option value="ISK">Iceland Krona (ISK)</option><option value="INR">Indian Rupee (INR)</option><option value="IDR">Indonesian Rupiah (IDR)</option><option value="IQD">Iraqi Dinar (IQD)</option><option value="ILS">Israeli New Shekel (ILS)</option><option value="JMD">Jamaican Dollar (JMD)</option><option value="JPY">Japanese Yen (JPY)</option><option value="JOD">Jordanian Dinar (JOD)</option><option value="KZT">Kazakhstani Tenge (KZT)</option><option value="KES">Kenyan Shilling (KES)</option><option value="KWD">Kuwaiti Dinar (KWD)</option><option value="KGS">Kyrgyzstani Som (KGS)</option><option value="LAK">Lao Kip (LAK)</option><option value="LVL">Latvian Lats (LVL)</option><option value="LBP">Lebanese Pound (LBP)</option><option value="LSL">Lesotho Loti (LSL)</option><option value="LRD">Liberian Dollar (LRD)</option><option value="LYD">Libyan Dinar (LYD)</option><option value="LTL">Lithuanian Litas (LTL)</option><option value="MOP">Macanese Pataca (MOP)</option><option value="MKD">Macedonian Denar (MKD)</option><option value="MGA">Malagasy Ariary (MGA)</option><option value="MWK">Malawian Kwacha (MWK)</option><option value="MYR">Malaysian Ringgit (MYR)</option><option value="MVR">Maldivian Rufiyaa (MVR)</option><option value="MRO">Mauritanian Ouguiya (MRO)</option><option value="MUR">Mauritian Rupee (MUR)</option><option value="MXN">Mexican Peso (MXN)</option><option value="MDL">Moldovan Leu (MDL)</option><option value="MNT">Mongolian Tugrik (MNT)</option><option value="MAD">Moroccan Dirham (MAD)</option><option value="MZN">Mozambique Metical (MZN)</option><option value="MMK">Myanma Kyat (MMK)</option><option value="NAD">Namibian Dollar (NAD)</option><option value="NPR">Nepalese Rupee (NPR)</option><option value="ANG">Netherlands Antillean Guilder (ANG)</option><option value="TWD">New Taiwan Dollar (TWD)</option><option value="NZD">New Zealand Dollar (NZD)</option><option value="NIO">Nicaraguan Cordoba Oro (NIO)</option><option value="NGN">Nigerian Naira (NGN)</option><option value="NOK">Norwegian Krone (NOK)</option><option value="OMR">Omani Rial (OMR)</option><option value="PKR">Pakistani Rupee (PKR)</option><option value="PAB">Panamanian balboa (PAB)</option><option value="PGK">Papua New Guinean Kina (PGK)</option><option value="PYG">Paraguay Guarani (PYG)</option><option value="PEN">Peruvian Nuevo Sol (PEN)</option><option value="PHP">Philippine Peso (PHP)</option><option value="PLN">Polish Zloty (PLN)</option><option value="GBP">Pound Sterling (GBP)</option><option value="QAR">Qatari Rial (QAR)</option><option value="RON">Romanian New Leu (RON)</option><option value="RUB">Russian Ruble (RUB)</option><option value="RWF">Rwandan Franc (RWF)</option><option value="SHP">Saint Helena Pound (SHP)</option><option value="WST">Samoan Tala (WST)</option><option value="STD">Sao Tome and Principe Dobra (STD)</option><option value="SAR">Saudi Riyal (SAR)</option><option value="RSD">Serbian Dinar (RSD)</option><option value="SCR">Seychelles Rupee (SCR)</option><option value="SLL">Sierra Leonean Leone (SLL)</option><option value="SGD">Singapore Dollar (SGD)</option><option value="SBD">Solomon Islands Dollar (SBD)</option><option value="SOS">Somali Shilling (SOS)</option><option value="ZAR">South African Rand (ZAR)</option><option value="KRW">South Korean Won (KRW)</option><option value="LKR">Sri Lankan Rupee (LKR)</option><option value="SRD">Suriname Dollar (SRD)</option><option value="SZL">Swazi Lilangeni (SZL)</option><option value="SEK">Swedish Krona (SEK)</option><option value="CHF">Swiss Franc (CHF)</option><option value="TJS">Tajikistani Somoni (TJS)</option><option value="TZS">Tanzanian Shilling (TZS)</option><option value="THB">Thai Baht (THB)</option><option value="TOP">Tongan Pa'anga (TOP)</option><option value="TTD">Trinidad and Tobago Dollar (TTD)</option><option value="TND">Tunisian Dinar (TND)</option><option value="TRY">Turkish Lira (TRY)</option><option value="TMT">Turkmenistan New Manat (TMT)</option><option value="AED">U.A.E. Dirham (AED)</option><option value="USD">U.S. Dollar (USD)</option><option value="UGX">Ugandan Shilling (UGX)</option><option value="UAH">Ukrainian Hryvnia (UAH)</option><option value="UYU">Uruguayan Peso (UYU)</option><option value="UZS">Uzbekistan Sum (UZS)</option><option value="VUV">Vanuatu Vatu (VUV)</option><option value="VEF">Venezuelan Bolivar Fuerte (VEF)</option><option value="VND">Vietnamese Dong (VND)</option><option value="YER">Yemeni Rial (YER)</option><option value="ZMK">Zambian Kwacha (ZMK)</option></optgroup></select>
```

Any help how can I fix this problem?!

Answer (score 1):

The xpath should do a `contains()` on the class attribute, not `text()`. The `text()` function returns the inner text of an element. Furthermore, specify the tag name instead of `*`:

```
currency = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@class, 'currencySelection_dropdown')]"))
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[contains(@class, 'currencySelection_dropdown')]"}

Comment: @AbdElRahmanAymen: please update your question with enough HTML to properly identify a locator. We will need all ancestor elements up to the body tag. And be sure to include any frames or iframes that might exist up the document tree on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
currency = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@name, 'currencySelection_dropdown')]"))
```

Your main issue was the non specification of the select tag and the name tag.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//select[@data-action="a-dropdown-select"]"}

Comment: Check if it's in an iframe.

Comment: It's not in iframe

Comment: Any shadow roots as well?

Comment: No, Check this link https://wtools.io/paste-code/b4pP

Comment: Try this one out.

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Comment: I use it a timer.sleep(5) with it but still giving same error

Answer (score 0):

Try with below WebElement using xpath:

```
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id=\"pmts-portal-bbb6ae6f-f79e-4a31-bc4a-7128cea6c9c9\"]"));
        element.click();
        Select selectCardCurrency = new Select(element);
        selectCardCurrency.selectByVisibleText("U.S. Dollar (USD)");
```